# Win 2008 R2 64bit VFP Scheduled Task Issue

Tags: windows, task, scheduler, visual-foxpro

I am attempting to migrate several Visual Fox Pro 9.0 apps from Win 2003 to Win 2008 R2 64 bit server.

The user logged in is the same user that the task is scheduled as to run.

When the app is run manually (browse to the folder & double click), it run successfully.

When the app is run via the Task Scheduler, it appears to run, but the app never ends in the task scheduler nor in the processes tab of the Task Manager.

AHIA,
LarryR...

Comment: If the EXE is run from a batch file, it completes successfully.

Answer (score 2):

If your VFP app is running on a 2008 R2 server and your clients are running Vista or Windows 7, then you may be having problems with SMB2 and Oplocks. This problem will manifest itself in strange hangs, file corruption and messages such as "Attempting to lock". We found that it was necessary to downgrade our clients to Windows XP to correct the problem. (For any of the legacy apps written in VFP 6 or older). VFP 9 apps appear to run fine on Vista and Win 7 if SMB2 is disabled on both client and server. (Both will automatically revert to SMB1). Please sse the following Microsoft articles:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/296264
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/visualfoxprogeneral/thread/6c62418d-08f8-495a-bbd4-f93151ec1f05

Disabling SMB2 is a relatively painless process, though you'll need to do it on each and every workstation and server that runs a legacy app.

Answer (score 2):

Had this same problem where our VFP 8.0 application would run fine when executed
manually but hang without error when setup as scheduled task under Windows Server 2008 R2. Got the basics of the solution from Brian in this thread here (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservermanager/thread/d47d116e-10b9-44f0-9a30-7406c86c2fbe) and this fix worked for us:

Setup the scheduled task to call a batch file which then calls the application. Then check these steps:

1. Make sure that the task is set to "configure for Windows Vista or
   Windows 2008" on the first page of the task properties (under the
   "general" tab)
2. Make sure that the task is set to "start in" the
   folder that contains the batch file: open the task properties, click
   on the "actions" tab, click on the action and then the "edit" button
   at the bottom. In the "Edit Action" Window there is a field for
   "start in (optional)" that you set to the path to the batch file.
3. Make sure that the task is running as an account that has explicit
   "Full access" permissions to all these things: The .bat file itself,
   the folder containing the .bat file, and the target files/folders
   that are affected by the .bat script. Inherited permissions didn't
   seem to work for me.
4. Make sure that the account running the task
   is a member of the local "administrators" group for this machine
5. Make sure that the task is set to "run whether logged on or not"
6. The Task should run successfully with expected output when you
   right-click on the task and select "run" If it does that then it
   will run successfully when you are logged off.

We had no problems with the same Visual FoxPro application under Windows 2003 so definetly a result of security/schedule changes in Windows 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the app I would put some simple logging to file at various places in your code so at least you can see where it is getting stuck. The STRTOFILE() function is probably the easiest way.
PS What is the relevance of the migration from 2003 to 2008? Are you saying it worked OK on 2003 and now doesn't on 2008?

Comment: It worked like a dream on 2003, then the server was upgraded to 2008 & all hell broke loose.  Currently the network admin runs the VFP apps via a batch file & this works.  I am currently re-writing in C# being VFP has been retired by MS, I do not have a choice.

Comment: Does the application have a user interface and does it appear? Have you tried forcing it to run manually from task scheduler or just on a timer?